# Scroll Container in C# winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll, flowlayoutpanel

I'm working on windows form project which has many controls on the form but I'm looking for a way that decrease my form, while seeing all of the controls by scroll up/down.

I am trying to use `FlowLayoutPanel` but it aligns horizontally or vertically.(I want to set control manually)

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: not a duplicate question. This is about any container. A sole answer about the panel does not make the question duplicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put all your controls inside a Panel control, and then set the form AutoScroll Property to true.  This way you can increase both width and length of the panel and the form  will automatically displays the scrollbar as needed.